# Customizing Kentico Kontent

Tags: kentico-kontent, kontent-ai

Is there a way to customize Kentico Kontent (cloud) to add a plugin?

Requirements for the plugin:

1. Can have HTML UI
2. Loads on every content item
3. Can extract text from content elements
4. Can select specific words from content item
5. Can modify specific words from content item

Does Kentico Kontent provide JS API for editing and modifying content in content item?

Thanks,
Abhijeet

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, they're called [custom elements](https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/develop-apps/integrate/content-editing-extensions).

1. HTML UI is actually [required](https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/develop-apps/integrate/content-editing-extensions#a-1-create-a-page) in order for a custom element to work
2. Multiple custom elements can be included in every content item
3. Use the [`getElementValue()`](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/custom-elements-js-api#a-getelementvalue-method) method + you can access the [`context`](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/custom-elements-js-api#a-context-object) object to retrieve additional information + you can [observe changes in other elements](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/custom-elements-js-api#a-observeelementchanges-method)
4. You can achieve that with your custom logic
5. So far, you can only [modify the contents/value of the custom element itself](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/custom-elements-js-api#a-setvalue-method)

- Browse the gallery of sample custom elements: https://kentico.github.io/kontent-custom-element-samples/gallery/
- Get inspired by their code: https://github.com/Kentico/kontent-custom-element-samples

Comment: Thanks I had a look at the custom elements. Unfortunately that does not solve our use cae. The Acrolinx(https://www.acrolinx.com/) integration we want to build needs to read and modify content of all elements on the content item. Also the integration itself does not want to be part of the content but wants to be part of the UI and act as a helper for content writer.

Comment: Modification of other elements can be achieved by utilizing the [Management API](https://docs.kontent.ai/reference/management-api-v2#operation/validate-project-content) in combination with custom elements. A slight disadvantage of this approach is that you wouldn't have immediate feedback in the UI. But it could work fine.

Comment: The inclusion in the UI can also be done easily by utilizing content snippets (that can be reused in multiple content types). There is a way to make it look like it's a part of the UI (see https://docs.kontent.ai/tutorials/develop-apps/integrate/content-editing-extensions#a-3-add-styles).